# Custom Delphi Tool Palette Grayed out

Tags: delphi, custom-component, delphi-11-alexandria, bpl

I am moving a project from Delphi XE8 to 11.2.

I have a custom Tool Palette `.bpl` that I have loaded into Delphi 11.2 using "Install Packages".

I can see pre-existing custom components in the `.dfm` files, but the components are grayed out in the Tool Palette. I can copy and paste a component from one `.dfm` to another, but cannot drag components in from the Tool Palette.

Everything works as normal in XE8.

Why might this be happening?

[image: grayed out components in palette]

Comment: Do you use VCL or FMX?

Comment: Modern Delphi versions use [ComponentPlatformsAttribute](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.ComponentPlatformsAttribute) to determine on which platform a specific component is supported. So you should edit your custom component library accordingly so Delphi will know what platforms your components actually supports. Check [Is there simpler way of saying that Delphi component/control is supported on all platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27486939/3636228) to see an example of how these attributes are used.